# Swipe to click admob ad in flutter app like tinder

Tags: flutter, admob

I want to integrate native ads from adMob, the google solution for integrating ads into app. However I cannot use them in a "normal" way because of the nature of my app.

The ad in my app cannot be clicked, and when my user swipe, I want the ad to react as if it's been clicked (opening the ad and all). I've been reading the adMob documentation but seen no ways to do that. Is there a way to make the ad react has if it has been clicked?

Answer (score -1):

You should not do that, this is considered a violation.

[AdMob & AdSense program policies](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3342054?hl=en&ref_topic=9756841)

> Please note that clicks on Google ads must result from genuine user interest, and any method that `artificially generates clicks` or impressions is strictly prohibited by our program policies.

> Publishers may not ask others to click their ads or `use deceptive implementation methods to obtain clicks`.